# How can I install commonly used developer tools?

Tags: development, application-development, metapackages

Is there a meta-package for installing commonly used developer tools such as cmake, autoconf, g++, etc.? The intent is to have roughly the same range of command-line tools as one has after installing XCode and the Mac SDK on Apple.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[build-essential](http://packages.ubuntu.com/build-essential) is the main one that springs to mind.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Answer (score 6):

The Ubuntu SDK is the recommended way to develop apps for Ubuntu.

The [Get Started page on the Ubuntu App Developer site](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/) will always contain up-to-date information on how to install the SDK and all related tools. In any case, here's how:

For Ubuntu 12.10 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS users:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-proper && sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk notepad-qml
```

Alternatively, for those using Ubuntu 13.04 or a development release:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-proper && sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk
```

Comment: Please update this answer :)

Comment: Done, please upvote ;)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `build-essential`, you might want to install:

> sudo apt-get install python-setup python-setuptools

And for terminal multiplexing:

> sudo apt-get install tmux screen

For ssh server:

> sudo apt-get install openssh-server