# Trying to install WI-FI Driver on fresh install with no internet

Tags: networking, drivers, compiling, gcc, tp-link

I have an Archer t4u V2 and I am trying to install the driver. I have the driver files but since it is a new install I don't have GCC or anything that I can use to compile the driver. Since I don't have internet I can't install anything to compile it. How can I either install GCC without internet or find a better way of installing the driver?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install TP-LINK Archer T4U driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802205/how-to-install-tp-link-archer-t4u-driver)

Comment: The purported duplicate assumes that you already have gcc, make, etc. already installed. He does not and is asking how to do so.

Comment: If you have the original Ubuntu installation DVD, USB or even SD card, you can use this method: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069550/unable-to-use-wifi-card-16-04-macos-dual-boot/1069949#1069949

Answer (score 0):

A .deb is package, as in `program.deb`, for Ubuntu like .exe is for Windows or .dmg is for Mac.

- How can I either install GCC without internet

  - You can get a .deb of the gcc from https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/gcc by clicking on your architecture at the bottom of the page and then selecting a mirror. Then move the download to your computer with something like a USB drive.
- or find a better way of installing the driver?

  - A better way to do this would be to let Ubuntu try to find the drive automatically. This is butter because Ubuntu will be able to find a .deb with the driver already compiled. The downside is that you will need to attach your computer to the Internet with by Ethernet for this to work. You didn't say what sort of computer you are having the problem on, but you should be able to get on-line with an Ethernet cable connected to the router and the computer with Ubuntu. Once you are on-line, in Ubuntu you can go to Additional Drivers program and search for unsupported hardware. Additional Drivers will download and install the missing drivers if there is one available form Ubuntu. [This can walk you though using Additional Drivers.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers#47511)

Comment: In order to compile the driver, he needs far more than gcc; he needs make, g++, fakeroot and a great deal more.

Comment: That is true. OP should install [Build Essentials](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24197/how-can-i-install-commonly-used-developer-tools#24198)